# How to make a sharp shadow?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

In the picture the sun makes a diffuse shadow on the interior wall of the poolhouse. I want this to be a sharp shadow (as would be the case in real life, with a full sun). Don't know if and how I have to change the wall material and/or the lighting (or whatever).

(the material of the wall is shown on the right panel, as "concrete")

[image]

Comment: Change the size of the sun lamp. See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44719/meaning-of-sun-lamp-size

Comment: That's perfect!

Answer (score 8):

A sun lamp with size 0 will give you a very sharp shadow:

[image]

As you increase the lamp's size it will give you much softer shadows.

[image]

[image]

related: [Meaning of Sun Lamp Size?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44719/meaning-of-sun-lamp-size)

Comment: In blender 2.8 Sun size has become "strength"

Comment: No, strength is how bright it is.

Comment: In Blender 2.9, set Angle to 0°.