# How can I make the shadows more defined?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, uv, shadows

[image: sword in a room]I have this project where some of the shadows are failing to show up (ex. the shadows that should be cast by the bars on the window).

How do I go about making the shadows appear?

External lighting setup:
[image: scene lighting]

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/278094)

Comment: a big light source is not going to give you defined shadows (like the bars of the windows) read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44725/1853

Comment: And so what would you suggest as far as scaling it? The scene has the light placed where I need it, and if I change the size of the light source the intensity will change.

Comment: You can add a second light, a small one (maybe a point light) just in front of the first one to create defined shadows

Comment: Will that then obscure the first light source?

Comment: @HelmarocPlume I edited your question to keep it about light and shadows. This is not a forum, but a question and answer site. Multiple unrelated questions on the same post are discouraged, as they lead to confusion and make it harder for others to find the information. Different questions should be asked in different posts. Please use the this link http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: Also please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was unaware of that when a friend had directed me here and I was anxious to ask my questions. I'll go ahead and remove the bits about the UV editing.

Comment: @HelmarocPlume but please keep posting any questions you have. Just do it in separate posts. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A big light source is going to give  you very soft shadows. The bigger the source, the softer the shadows (think of the light on an overcast day, when the sun is diffused by clouds). A small light source (like direct sun or a street light) will make harder shadows.

---

[image]

Adding a second point light in front of the original source will give you defined shadows while keeping the light directon You might want to make the original soft source less bright)

[image]

Comment: Am I able to affect the direction of the light from the point lamp? I've added one in front of my scene, but it doesn't seem to be doing much, if at all.

Comment: play with the intensity.