# Sun lamp gives horizon glow not direct light?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Simple scene: cycles , add sun lamp and the lighting is coming from the horizon, not from one singular direction?

Clearly a setting somewhere i've missed. any ideas?
[image]
[image]

**Blend file:**

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cETvV.jpg

Thanks
JK

Comment: You need to decrease Sun Lamp Size value to 1 for example. Technical explanation is here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44719/meaning-of-sun-lamp-size

Answer (score 1):

Considering the scene units I was using, my sun lamp was astronomically huge. I reduced its size and it began functioning properly.