# Point light in Blender 2.90.1 not working

Tags: light

My point light is not working. I edit all the options and it is not showing in my model.

The model is imported from SketchUp (in case this is important), also I have extreme amateur knowledge of 3D programs.

[image: :(]

Here's the Blender File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ybeimexele5xwu3/Exterior.blend?dl=0

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with your current light.  But if you delete the light and make a new one, it should work.  It did for me when I tried it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of Sun Lamp Size?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44719/meaning-of-sun-lamp-size)

Answer (score 4):

Your radius is too big, using something like 1 or 2 should work, also make sure your light color is not too dark

[image]

Comment: Thank you! that was actually the problem n_n

Comment: If you don't plan a night scene with Point lights you can use a Sun light (turn down the strength to 1 and change to angle) or even better, for more realistic light, you can use _Sky Texture_ shader node or an _Environment Texture_ shader node + an HDRI image.

Comment: @NatAcuña -- don't forget to "accept" this answer if satisfied.  I'm sure Emir would appreciate the "helper points" if you do this.