# Point Light not showing in viewport or render. 2.91.0

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

When I add a point light to the scene nothing changes in the viewport or render. I have tried eevee and cycles. I also upped the power and radius. I also made sure to check that the light is not hidden in either view. Lastly, sun does not work at all either. Any ideas?

Edit: I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but I just went into render viewpoint shading: rendered and everything is completely whited out but the point light still doesn't work.

[image: Image of white render view.]

Comment: could you upload the blend? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Could it be : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200646/point-light-in-blender-2-90-1-not-working/200652#200652