# Is it possibile to retain a glossy material when the object is made shadeless in cycles?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I've used glossy material shaders for a spaceship but, as you can see in the picture, the hand in the foreground is projecting a horrible shadow. I made the object shadeless but I lost the glossy effect as a result (this is because of the emission shader). Is there a way to keep the object glossy but shadeless at the same time? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to make the hand cast no shadow. The other object cannot be shaded (glossy) and shadeless at the same time:

[image]

If you want to tone down the shadows you can make it partially transparent for lights and shaded for camera:

[What is a shadow ray?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23500/what-is-a-shadow-ray/23505#23505)

Instead of blue transparency input grey transparent shader (so it's not tinted), and instead of green diffuse input your hand material.

Comment: Fantastic! You actually solved my problem, it was enough to get rid of the hand shadow. How could I have missed that option??? Wonderful, now everything is perfect and I also want to thank you about the information about the shadow ray because I was rather confused. I'm going to save it and keep it for future references. In the meantime, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One way to reduce the 'hard' shadow (rather than eliminate it completely) is to increase the size of the Lamp - since a larger lamp will produce softer shadows.

For example, the default lamp size of 0.1 produces an ugly hard shadow :

[image: hard shadow]

Increasing the lamp size to 1.0 produces a much less obvious shadow :

[image: soft shadow]

Comment: I've already done that, but that's not what I need. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No worries - I did expect that since your description was quite specific to being shadeless - jist thought it worth a mention.

Comment: Yes, it's always good to know all options available. I appreciated it!