# Blender remove fireflies (Substance painter node)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, noise-reduction

I have a problem here on my last project with noise. For some reason I have some white dots on this render, do you have any idea how can I fix it?

On my scene, I have bean used portal lights for each window, and HDRi image for the lights and this render is done with 20.000 samples, and still I have noise.

I've been searching a way to remove this so I've tried some advice from [7 Ways to Get Rid of Fireflies Once and For All](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/) and nothing works for me.

Afters this I found out that the responsible for these fireflies is my Substance Painter node, removing that node and putting just a simple node like Diffuse on his place and everything will be fine.

[image]

Do you have any idea what should I do to solve this problem? 
Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/41803/935) is relevant.

Comment: When you say that you rendered with 20.000 sampling, did you mean twenty (20) or twenty thousand (20,000)

Comment: What is your material setup on the windows? The Glass BDSF shader produces very noisy results for light passing through it. Try using a Transparent BDSF Shader instead.

Answer (score 1):

Really good question Duarte! This is a common problem that I have faced many times. There is a despekle node built into the Blender compositor, as well as other third party softwares that can help you with this. Try rendering with a higher sample count. 20 is *very* low. GIMP is a free image editing software that you can use to remove fireflies, as I have many times! [Video tutorial on removing fireflies in blender -](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovb425IWQis) [Remove noise in GIMP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovb425IWQis) I have included an image below on how to get rid of fireflies in GIMP. Hope this helps you some! [image: Before][image: During][image: After]

Comment: "Try rendering with a higher sample count. 20 is very low", I've render this scene with 20k not 20 xD

Comment: Ah. I see. You should probably say 20k or 20,000 instead of 20.000