# White points in my render

Tags: rendering, image

How can I eliminate or reduce the white points in the rendered image?

[image]

Comment: Read the links marded as duplicates and also: [will increasing samples reduce fireflies?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86635/will-increasing-samples-reduce-fireflies) and [why do fireflies increase with samples when using HDR](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41803/why-do-fireflies-increase-with-number-of-samples-when-using-a-hdri-light-source)

Comment: and [fireflies on glossy material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40040/fireflies-noise-on-glossy-material/40142#40142)

Comment: and Blender guru's article on how to reduce fireflies: https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies