# Lamp VS. Emission Object (difference)

Tags: light

Yeah, simple as that.

Why do most of the people use a plane which emits light (in most cases) and not a lamp? What's the difference between them? When do I use a lamp and when the emission node?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/89665/29586

Comment: Found a nice answer her: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8039/area-light-vs-emissive-polygon Would recommend this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4HwnnLRvtI&t=263s